# Why can't I get anything back for Bing API

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, bing

I just can't get any thing back from Bing img search API, here is the details of this API.

https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c

Since HttpClient is deprecated so I use `httpURLconnection`, can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code ?

All the params and the key are good, I have tested on the web site.

```
public void run() {
            
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(8000);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                                    
                connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "562eaaada4b644f2bea31a454f26d905");

                OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream params =new DataOutputStream(out);
                params.writeBytes("q=dog&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Moderate");
                out.close();
                
                connection.connect();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                
                
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                }

                Message message = new Message();
                message.what = SHOW_RESPONSE;
                message.obj = response.toString();
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your doing "POST" call for ImageInsights.

> ImageInsights

```
connection .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

and the here contents are wrong

```
  params.writeBytes("q=dog&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Moderate");//
it takes post post body not query param String.
```

For Search api is "GET" call not "POST" call

> Search Api

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search[?q][&count][&offset][&mkt][&safeSearch]
here every this is in url query string, you have write it in outputstream
```

check below sample(you can try there api sample )

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=cats&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Moderate");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(8000);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
```